# Triangles in a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: triangles, quadrilateral

Consider a cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ where

$|DA|\lt |AB|=|BC|\lt |CD|$, $E:|BE|\bot |AC|, E\in |CD|$  , $F:|EF|\text{ }||\text{ }|BC|,F\in |AB|$.

The task is to prove that |FB|=|FD|, that is, that $\Delta FDB$ is isosceles.

I have been able to prove some statements about the quadrilateral, like tha fact that the triangles formed by the diagonals opposite each other have to be similar, but I am struggling to prove anything of use regarding $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta FDB$.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do E and F lie on the circle?

Comment: They lie on $|CD|$ and $|AB|$ respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the circle through $A, B, C, D$ and denote by $G$ the point of intersections of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$. Furthermore, call $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ the circles through $AGD$ and $DGC$, respectively.

Because we have the equality of angles $\angle BAC = \angle BCA = \angle BDA$, where we have used that the triangle $ABC$ is isosceles and carried an angle through the circle, we deduce that $\triangle BGA \sim \triangle BAD$, which implies $BA^2 = BG\cdot BD$. Hence, $\mathcal{X}$ is tangent to $BA$ at $A$. In analogous fashion we deduce that $\mathcal{Y}$ is tangent to $BC$ at $C$.

If we call $M$ the other point of intersection of $BE$ with circle $\mathcal{C}$ we know, since $BE\perp AC$ and $ABC$ is isosceles, that that $BM$ is a diameter of $\mathcal{C}$ and hence $MC\perp BC$ and $MA\perp BA$. Because of the tangencies proves above the center of $\mathcal{X}$ has to lie on $AM$ and that of $\mathcal{Y}$ on $MC$.

Call $X$ the intersection of $AM$ and the parallel line through $E$ to $MC$. We have then $$\angle DAM = \angle DCM = \angle DEX.$$ Hence we deduce $DAEX$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Now call $L$ the intersection of $DX$ with $MC$. We have that

$$\begin{align*}
 \angle LDC 
&= \angle XDE\\
&= \angle XAE   &\;\mbox{(by previous cyclic quadrilateral)}\\
&= \angle XAC - \angle EAC\\
&= \angle MAC - \angle EAC\\
&= \angle MCA - \angle ECA &\mbox{(since BM is perp. bisector of AC)}\\
&= \angle MCE
\end{align*}$$

Hence, $LD = LC$ and so $L$ lies in the perpendicular bisector of $DC$. But the center of $\mathcal{Y}$, which also lies in that perpendicular bisector, since $DC$ is a chord, has to be in $MC$ since this is orthogonal to the tangent $BC$ at the tangency point $C$. We conclude $L$ is the center of $\mathcal{Y}$.

Now, $\angle DAF = \angle DAB = 180 - \angle BCD = 180 - \angle FED$. Hence, $DAFE$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, but $DAEX$ was also a cyclic quadrilateral, and since these circles share the points $D, A, E$, we conclude $DAFEX$ is a cyclic pentagon.

Now, $\angle FDL = \angle FDX = 180 - \angle XEF$, using the above cyclic pentagon and, furthermore, by contruction $XE || MC$ and $FE || BC$ so that $\angle XEF = \angle MCB = 90$, since $MC$ lies on a diameter of $\mathcal{Y}$ and $BC$ a tangent. We deduce $\angle FDL = 90$.

We have proven above that $L$ is the center of $\mathcal{Y}$, and since $D$ is on $\mathcal{Y}$ then $DF$ is a tangent to this circle since we just proved $\angle FDL = 90$. Hence, transporting angles, first on $\mathcal{Y}$, using this tangent, and then on $\mathcal{C}$ we conclude
$$\angle FDG = \angle DCG = \angle DCA = \angle DBA = \angle DBF,$$ that is, $\triangle FDB$ is isosceles, as desired.

Here is a drawing:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Quadrilateral ABCD]

Draw $AE$ and $FD$.

Observe that, $AFED$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Also, since $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles, $BE$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AC$.

Thus, $\angle FDB=\angle FDE-\angle BDE=\angle FDE-\angle BDC=\angle FAE-\angle BAC=\angle FAE-\angle FAC=\angle CAE=\angle ACE=\angle ACD=\angle ABD=\angle FBD$.

Therefore, $\triangle FDB$ is isosceles.

Edit : The reason why $AFED$ is cyclic is because since $EF$ is parallel to $BC$, $\angle AFE=\angle ABC=180-\angle ADC=180-\angle ADE$ and hence $AFED$ is cyclic.[It's opposite angles are supplementary.]   ( Credit : User @V.S.e.H.)

Comment: How did you conclude that $\angle FDE - \angle BDC = \angle FAE - \angle BAC$?

Comment: @bodil Since $ABCD$ and $AFED$ are cyclic quadrilaterals,  $\angle FDE=\angle FAE$ and $\angle BDC=\angle BAC$

Comment: The part about $AFED$ being cyclic is key to this proof. Can you include it in your answer, and I will upvote.

Comment: @bodil Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @bodil Thanks for upvoting.